# In full calendar hightlight custom dates

Tags: javascript, date, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I want to show on the calendar, that what dates are free dates in the year. For these, i want to set a red background.

My problem is, that with this code, it gives the red background to all the dates.

I am using this in the dayRender event.

```
var unnep_napok = 
    [
        "2019-01-12",
        "2019-01-15"
    ];

$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                events: valami,
                lang: 'hu',
                dayClick: function(event) {
                    $(cell).removeClass('ui-widget-content');
                    $(cell).addClass('holiday');
                    $(this).css('background-color', 'green');
                },
                defaultView: 'month',
                contentHeight: 'auto',
                slotEventOverlap: false,

                eventRender: function(eventObj, $el) {
                    $el.popover({
                          title: ' ',
                          content: eventObj.description,
                          trigger: 'hover',
                          placement: 'top',
                          container: 'body'
                    });
                },



                dayRender: function (date, cell) {
                    for(i = 0; i < unnep_napok.length; i++ )
                    {
                        cell.css("background-color", "red");
                    }
                }


            });
```

**Update with compare:**

```
    dayRender: function (date, cell) {
                    for(i = 0; i < unnep_napok.length; i++ )
                    {
                        if(date == unnep_napok[i] )
                        {
                            cell.css("background-color", "red");
                        }
                    }
                }
```

> **Update 2, formatting array elements:**

```
dayRender: function (date, cell)
```

> ```
>               {
>                   for(i = 0; i < unnep_napok.length; i++ )
>                   {
>                       var datum = unnep_napok[i].moment.format('yyyy-mm-dd');
>
>                       if(date.getDate() == datum )
>                       {
>                           cell.css("background-color", "red");
>                       }
>                   }
>               }
> ```

Comment: in `dayRender` you are given the `date` which is being rendered. You can use that to compare against the list of the dates you wish to highlight (unnep_napok in your case) and therefore decide whether to go ahead and change the background colour or not.

Comment: Sorry, but my english isnt very good. Can show show me a sample code for that?

Comment: Ok I will write it more simply: Compare the `date` coming from `dayRender` to each date item in `unnek_napok`. If it is identical to one item, then change the background colour. If it never matches any item, then never change the colour.

Comment: Once you understand what I have written, then coding it should be quite easy.

Comment: I updated my post, can you take a look at it? You mean the compare like this? Its not doing anything.

Comment: `date` will be a momentJS object, not a string, so it can never be equal to the strings in your array. You can either 1) [format](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) that to a string in "yyyy-mm-dd" format and then compare, _or_ 2) [parse](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/) the strings into moment objects and then [compare](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/) the objects instead. Either way is fine

Comment: I updated my code again. Now, the calendar isnt working. Am i formatting the array values wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following your update, there are still some problems which could be resolved by reading the documentation (and my earlier comments) more carefully:

1) I didn't give you the literal values to use in the "format" command. Did you read the [documentation](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) fully? As you can see, the correct format would be `YYYY-MM-DD` (big letters not small letters).

2) `unnep_napok[i].moment.format` ...this is not how you [create a momentJS object](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/now/). I would expect your browser gave an error in the console about this.

3) But anyway 2) is not important really, because as I mentioned in my last comment, it's the `date` value which you need to format ... your unnep_napok values are already strings!!

4) `date.getDate()` .. I don't know where you got this from?? MomentJS does not document any such function.

This should work for you:

```
dayRender: function (date, cell) 
{
  for(i = 0; i < unnep_napok.length; i++ )
  {
    if(date.format('YYYY-MM-DD') == unnep_napok[i])
    {
      cell.css("background-color", "red");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Now that works, and i understand it also. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

A running example based on ADyson's answer. I have also covered popover example for a quick start.

.popover works this way $(element).popover and doesn't work using element.popover

Running example: https://jsfiddle.net/alifaraze/mr53d7nz/8/

HTML

```
 <div id="calendar"></div>
```

Script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var unnep_napok = [
    "2019-01-23",
    "2019-01-25"
  ];
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    events: [{
        id: 1,
        title: 'Full Day Event',
        start: '2019-01-02',
        end: '2019-01-03',
        description: 'A full day event description'
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        title: 'Whole Week Event',
        start: '2019-01-06',
        end: '2019-01-10',
        description: 'Whole week event description'
      }
      // more events here
    ],
    eventRender: function(event, element) {
      $(element).popover({
        title: function() {
          return "<B>" + event.title + "</B>";
        },
        placement: 'auto',
        html: true,
        trigger: 'click',
        animation: 'false',
        content: function() {
          return "<h4>"+ event.description+"</h4>"
        },
        container: 'body'
      });
    },
    dayRender: function(date, cell) {
      for (i = 0; i < unnep_napok.length; i++) {
        if (date.format('YYYY-MM-DD') == unnep_napok[i]) {
          cell.css("background-color", "red");
        }
      }
    }
  });
})
```